# Scikit Kmeans tutorial, n_runs and n_init different purpose?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/plot_document_clustering.html

In the above documentation, we are running KMeans. The KMeans class has an n_init parameter like so:

```
kmeans = KMeans(
    n_clusters=true_k,
    max_iter=100,
    n_init=1,
)
```

Additionally, the fit_and_evaluation function from the docs uses an n_runs parameter for the number of times to rerun kmeans.

```
for seed in range(n_runs):
    km.set_params(random_state=seed)
    t0 = time()
    km.fit(X)
    train_times.append(time() - t0)
    scores["Homogeneity"].append(metrics.homogeneity_score(labels, km.labels_))
    scores["Completeness"].append(metrics.completeness_score(labels, km.labels_))
    scores["V-measure"].append(metrics.v_measure_score(labels, km.labels_))
    scores["Adjusted Rand-Index"].append(
        metrics.adjusted_rand_score(labels, km.labels_)
    )
    scores["Silhouette Coefficient"].append(
        metrics.silhouette_score(X, km.labels_, sample_size=2000)
    )
```

Why are both n_runs and n_init needed? both parameters just restart the process with a different initialization

Comment: `fit_and_evaluate()` function also includes bit where each call to `fit()` is timed and those times are collected in `evaluation` and `evaluation_std` lists. Which isn't possible with a single call to `fit()`, right?